# Finding subset of disjunctive intervals with maximal weights

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm I could use to solve this, not the code. I wondered about using linear programming with relaxation, but maybe there are more efficient ways for solving this?

**The problem**

I have set of intervals with weights. Intervals can overlap. I need to find maximal sum of weights of disjunctive intervals subset.

**Example**

*Intervals with weights :*

```
|--3--|          |---1-----|
    |----2--| |----5----|
```

*Answer: 8*

Comment: Are you looking for an exact algorithm or an approximation algorithm? LP relaxation would usually not give you integral solutions outright, but maybe check for a formulation with consecutive-ones constraint matrix: such a matrix is automatically totally unimodular and optimal basic solutions will be integral.

Comment: I saw something similar in THE ALGORITHMS BOOK http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0262033844/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_2?pf_rd_p=486539851&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0262032937&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=06QJDKMCA5ETPXCSZ09S I am not suggesting that you buy it, just too lazy to find another reference. The algorithm in that book may have been different, but it might inspire you.

Comment: I owe this book, I'll look into it when I'll be in home. 
I am looking for an exact algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean you'd prefer an exact algorithm (which may take exponential time, but is ok when the number of intervals is small) over an approximation algorithm (works even when there are many intervals, but answers may be non-optimal)? How many intervals do you have, anyway?

Comment: Not a clue, I don't know testcases.

Comment: So is this problem homework? And hasn't your professor told you the size of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an **exact O(nlog n) DP algorithm** in mind.  Since this is homework, here is a clue:

Sort the intervals by right edge position as Saeed suggests, then number them up from 1.  Define f(i) to be the highest weight attainable by using only intervals that do not extend to the right of interval i's right edge.

**EDIT: Clue 2:** Calculate each f(i) in increasing order of i.  Keep in mind that each interval will either be present or absent.  To calculate the score for the "present" case, you'll need to hunt for the "rightmost" interval that is compatible with interval i, which will require a binary search through the solutions you've already computed.

That was a biggie, not sure I can give more clues without totally spelling it out ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "rightmost". I don't know if I think right. f(i) is a set, with interval numbers, which have the highest weights and are disjunctive?

Comment: Is this algorithm described in some book or this is your idea?

Comment: @Pawel: It may be in a book somewhere, but I arrived at it myself.  By "rightmost, compatible" I mean that interval whose right edge is greatest yet still at or to the left of the left edge of interval i.  And sorry I was unclear: f(i) is actually not a set of non-overlapping intervals itself but just the weight of such a set.  So in fact we compute just the weight of each candidate solution; actually enumerating the intervals in an optimal solution requires tracing back like what is done for other DP algorithms.

Comment: Could you spell it out now? I did it in some other way, but it would be nice to know how it should be done.

Comment: @Pawel: First observe that if a > b, then f(a) >= f(b) -- that's because in the worst case we could always just choose, for f(a), the same set of intervals that we chose for f(b) (and leave some "room" at the right-hand end).  Now, we want to calculate f(i), and we have already calculated f(j) for j < i.  There are 2 cases: either the ith interval will be present or it won't -- we just need to evaluate the weights of both cases and choose the maximum.  If the ith interval isn't present, then the weight will be f(i-1) (remember this must be >= all f(j) for j < i-1)...

Comment: @Pawel: ...  If interval i *is* present, we need to look for the biggest solution that leaves room for it at the end.  That means looking for the largest j (and therefore the largest f(j)) such that rightedge(j) <= leftedge(i).  Because we sorted the edges by their right endpoints before we started, we can use a binary search to find this j.  The weight for this case will be f(j) + weight(i).  So set f(i) to max(f(i-1), f(j) + weight(i)), where j is the outcome of that binary search, and start working on f(i+1).  If there are n intervals, f(n) will be the maximum possible weight.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Thanks. I just finished semester, so I'll try to write it in my free time :)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no weight it's easy you can use greedy algorithm by sorting the intervals by the end time of them, and in each step get the smallest possible end time interval.

but in your case I think It's NPC (should think about it), but you can use similar greedy algorithm by Value each interval by Weigth/Length, and each time get one of a possible intervals in sorted format, Also you can use simulated annealing, means each time you will get best answer by above value with probability `P` (p is near to `1`) or select another interval with probability 1-`P`. you can do it in while loop for `n` times to find a good answer.

Comment: You can use backtracking for exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

Consider the following graph: Create a node for each interval. If interval I1 and interval I2 do not overlap and I1 comes before I2, add a directed edge from node I1 to node I2. Note this graph is acyclic. Each node has a cost equal to the length of the corresponding interval.

Now, the idea is to find the longest path in this graph, which can be found in polynomial time for acyclic graphs (using dynamic programming, for example). The problem is that the costs are in the nodes, not in the edges. Here is a trick: split each node v into v' and v''. All edges entering v will now enter v' and all edges leaving v will now leave v''. Then, add an edge from v' to v'' with the node's cost, in this case, the length of the interval. All the other edges will have cost 0.

Well, if I'm not mistaken the longest path in this graph will correspond to the set of disjoint intervals with maximum sum.

Comment: Nice.  But can't you do longest path for DAGs in linear time?

Comment: Yes, I think you can do it in linear time in the size of the graph (nodes + edges). One observation though: the number of the edges can be O(n^2), where n is the number of intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution (end to end) is explained here: http://tkramesh.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/dynamic-programming-1-weighted-interval-scheduling/

Answer (score 1):

You could formulate this problem as a general IP (integer programming) problem with binary variables indicating whether an interval is selected or not. The objective function will then be a weighted linear combination of the variables. You would then need appropriate constraints to enforce disjunctiveness amongst the intervals...That should suffice given the `homework` tag.

Also, just because a problem can be formulated as an integer program (solving which is NP-Hard) it does not mean that the problem class itself is NP-Hard. So, as Ulrich points out there may be a polynomially-solvable formulation/algorithm such as formulating/solving the problem as a linear program.